# JMeter write to CSV with values with comma in the same column

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am writing some values to CSV. One of the columns values has a comma like "Hello, World".
**When I write to CSV it writes the Hello in column 1 and World is in column2.**

**I would like both to be written in the same column. I have tried quite a few options but no luck. This is the code I am using**

```
**///////////////Create CSV File**
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

String path = "ExtractedFiles/";
String dataExtractionCSVFile = path+ "ExtractedData.${DateTime}.csv";
f = new FileOutputStream(dataExtractionCSVFile, true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p);
print("comments");
f.close();
vars.put("dataExtractionCSVFile",dataExtractionCSVFile)
```

**//////////////Write Values to CSV File**

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
comments = vars.get("comments");

dataExtractionCSVFile = vars.get("dataExtractionCSVFile");
f = new FileOutputStream(dataExtractionCSVFile, true);
        p = new PrintStream(f);  
        this.interpreter.setOut(p);     
        print(comments);
        f.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such concept as "column" in CSV, if you use comma as a delimiter and your `comments` contains a comma the solution would be surrounding it with quotation marks.

Something like:

```
print("\"" + comments + "\"");
```

If you're going to re-use the CSV file in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) - make sure to set "Allow Quoted Data" to `True`

[image]

Also be aware that using scripting for writing the data into a file is potentially dangerous, in case of running the script with more than 1 thread (user) you might run into a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) so either make sure to put your script under the [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) or switch to i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin)